# transfer function in z-form from Difference equation, Matlab

Tags: matlab, difference-equations

Is there any function to get a transfer function in z form from difference equation in Matlab?

Comment: You might find [`sym2poly`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym2poly.html) useful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Matlab has a built-in function [Z-transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ztrans.html)

Comment: Cool function!  Never knew that existed.